# Distinct values of an SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table

[image]

and I want the 10 distinct rows with the highest score ordered descending.
So I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `highscores` GROUP BY userID  ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10  ;
```

which is not correct because it returns:

[image]

Then I tried:

`SELECT distinct(userID),userName,userLastname,score FROM`highscores`ORDER BY score DESC  ;`

which is not correct too, because it doesn't really returns distinct rows based on userID.

[image]

And this is the result that I want:

[image]

I want to keep the highest score of each player(different `userID`) for the 10 first players. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your first result?

Comment: @EddieJamsession I post the result

Comment: Ok, now it is clear :)

Comment: You need to use aggregation function Max() and group by userID, if you want I can describe it in more details.

Comment: @EddieJamsession thanks for your comment, it helps a lot, I wrote an answer with the right query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right query is:

```
SELECT userName, userLastname, userID, MAX( score ) 
FROM  `highscores` 
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY MAX( score ) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Thanks to EddieJamsession's comment.

Comment: You need to use alias for Max( score ) for more clarity, like this:`SELECT userName, userLastname, userID, MAX( score ) as max_score 
FROM  highscores 
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY max_score DESC 
LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    highscore a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  userID, MAX(score) score
            FROM    highscore
            GROUP   BY userID
        ) b ON  a.userID = b.userID 
                AND a.score = b.score
ORDER   BY score DESC
LIMIT   10
```

*this does not handle ties, though.*

Answer (score 0):

[In MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) you can use the DISTINCT operator with more than one column. The combination of all columns will be used to define the uniqueness of the row in the result set.

For example, to get the unique combination of city and state from the customers table, you use the following query:

SELECT DISTINCT state, city
FROM customers
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY state, city

Comment: I tried this `SELECT DISTINCT userID,userName,userLastname,score FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 ;` but still is not correct because there are rows with the same player and different score. I want to be distinct based on `userID`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question update:

```
SELECT h1.* FROM highscores h1
LEFT JOIN highscores h2 ON h1.userId = h2.userId and h1.score < h2.score
WHERE h2.score IS NULL
ORDER BY h1.score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

A different approach would be:

```
SELECT h1.* FROM highscores h1
JOIN (
    SELECT userId, max(score) maxScore FROM highscores
    GROUP BY userId
) h2 ON h1.userId = h2.userId and h1.score = h2.maxScore
ORDER BY h1.score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: because `SELECT * FROM highscores
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10` does not return unique rows based on userID, there are rows where userID is the same and all the other columns are different.

Comment: That's what I want, and yes I can have many equal `userID` with different scores

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  userID,userName,userLastname, MAX(score) as score 
 FROM highscores 
  WHERE userID in (
    SELECT distinct userID FROM highscores )
  ORDER BY score DESC
  LIMIT 10;
```